# CGAL::centroid for Polyheron /3D

Tags: cgal

I use already the fonction CGAL::centroid for Polygon_2. It works well :

```
return CGAL::centroid(vertices_begin (), vertices_end(),CGAL::Dimension_tag<0>());
```

When I'm trying to use the function in Polyhedron_3, it does not works.

CGAL::centroid shows only 3 possibles signatures returning 2D returns only.

Have you an example for using 3D centroid ?

Many thanks for help.

Gilles

Answer (score 0):

In the CGAL::Polygon the "vertices" are points, in the Polyhedron_3 they are Vertex_handles. You could use a boost::transform_iterator to obtain a sequence of points.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/afabri/6a77a8d8a3f4ddd18aba) you can see how I did this for CGAL::Surface_mesh

Answer (score 0):

Use `points_begin()`, `points_end()` instead.